# Loops and switch, convert phone slogan to number help, switch won't run (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to write this code that converts a phone slogan such as CASHNOW to the corresponding number. I think that i have it laid out but i can not get my loop to run with my switch statement, or output the numbers as they run. I need it to run the first 7 letters only and output them with the hyphen like a phone number. There is another thread like this one but it is more complicated than the one i'm trying to run i believe. I'm pretty new to Java so anything helps! Please and thank you!

```
package slogan_to_phone_number;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Galde_Project_8 {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Variables
    char currentChar;
    int strLen;
    String input_num;
    int output_num = 0;
    int number = 0;

    // Get user input

    System.out.println("Enter the phone number (With letters): ");
    input_num = console.nextLine();

    input_num = input_num.toUpperCase();

    strLen = input_num.length();

    currentChar = input_num.charAt(0);


    // for statement

    for (currentChar = 0; currentChar >= 7; currentChar ++)
    {

        switch(currentChar)
        {
        case 'A' : case 'B' : case 'C' : output_num = 2; break;
        case 'D' : case 'E' : case 'F' : output_num = 3; break;
        case 'G' : case 'H' : case 'I' : output_num = 4; break;
        case 'J' : case 'K' : case 'L' : output_num = 5; break;
        case 'M' : case 'N' : case 'O' : output_num = 6; break;
        case 'P' : case 'Q' : case 'R' : case 'S' : output_num = 7; break;
        case 'T' : case 'U' : case 'V' : output_num = 8; break;
        case 'W' : case 'X' : case 'Y' : case 'Z' : output_num = 9; break;
        }

        System.out.print(output_num);

    { // end of for loop

    }

}

    // Output


}
```

}

Comment: Do you have to use a switch statement? I think `"ABC".contains(String.valueOf(currentChar))` looks a little cleaner.

Comment: My professor wants us to use a switch statement, they can be bulky but seem to work well for the projects we've had so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `currentChar` as your `for` loop's counter because it's holding your `char` for the switch. Use something new like `int x = 0` instead.

If you use `currentChar` as your counter, you'll lose the character you're checking. You'll also want to iterate over the phone number in your loop, so move your `currentChar = input_num.charAt(0);` into the for loop:

```
for(int x=0; x<=7; x++)
{
    currentChar = input_num.charAt(x);
    ...
```